# Drupal 7. How do I change the CSS of the node when I click "Read More?"

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm creating a custom theme (as a n00b). Basically, I display content on the main page as small div blocks.

my **node.tpl.php** looks something like this:

```
<div class="content-block">
    default node.tpl.php stuff here
</div>
```

This works OK on the front page. However, when I click "Read More," to take me to the full article page, **/node/[nodeId]**, obviously, it still shows as the little CSS content-block div.

I'd like to show the full article using a different CSS class. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some best ways to accomplish that.

- First of all I am not sure, whether you are using separate front page tpl or not. If not then please try to use **page--front.tpl.php**. Where you can provide your desired format to create the proper front page. Why this is needed, cause you won't need to modify the node.tpl.php file. So inside this front tpl file you can put your desired code.
  `<div class="content-block">
      default node.tpl.php stuff here
  </div>`
  Also you can use the **Panel** module to create a front page. So you won't be needed to modify the nope tpl file. Always try to avoid modifying tpl file. **Panel** module makes it easier.
- Secondly, you should not touch the **node.tpl.php** file. Once you will modify the file, you won't be able to re-define as default. So keep that as it is and revert back it to the default  file. Now if you send some article link, it won't break.

So this is it. If this helps you, then please like :)

**Keep Drupalizing :)**